# セレクト結果レコードに対して、該当レコードの前後に来るidカラム値を取得したい

Tags: mysql

**前提**
・MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `pref_id` = 5;
```

id　name　pref_id
・248　佐藤　5 
・250　鈴木　5
・317　山田　5
・400　中村　5

※idカラムには、AUTO_INCREMENTを設定しています

---

**質問1**

・この時、任意のidを引数として、前後のレコードがあればidを取得したいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

例1 ／ 250を渡す
・前のレコードidとして248、後のレコードidとして317を取得したい

例2 ／ 400を渡す
・前のレコードidとして317を取得したい

---

**質問2**
・質問1の内容を、前提のSELECT文に組み込む(一緒にまとめて実行する)ことは出来るでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

分析関数なら`LAG()`と`LEAD()`ですが、MySQLで実現するには副問い合わせでしょうか。

```
SELECT id
     , name
     , pref_id
     , (SELECT MAX(id) FROM user t2 WHERE t2.id < t1.id AND t2.pref_id = 5)
     , (SELECT MIN(id) FROM user t2 WHERE t2.id > t1.id AND t2.pref_id = 5)
  FROM user t1
 WHERE pref_id = 5
 ORDER BY id
```

ソート順がキー以外の場合はもう少し複雑になるかと思います。

Comment: 副問い合わせするぐらいなら一行ずらして自己結合、とか思いましたがどっちもどっちでしょうか。

Comment: @unarist 抽出条件が付いているので`ROW_NUMBER()`のないMySQLで自己結合は難しいかと思います。変数を使えば行けるかもしれませんが…

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENTなので、LAST_INSERT_IDみたいな何か便利なものがもしかしたらあるかも、と思ったのですが…。副問い合わせで実装すれば良いことが分かりました

Answer (score 1):

MySQLでも動かなかったらごめんなさい！自己結合だとこんな書き方になるんでしょうか。

```
SELECT 
  U1.ID, 
  MAX(U1.NAME) AS NAME,
  MAX(U1.PREF_ID) AS PREF_ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN U1.ID > U2.ID THEN U2.ID ELSE NULL END) AS PREVIOUS,
  MIN(CASE WHEN U1.ID < U2.ID THEN U2.ID ELSE NULL END) AS NEXT
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM USER WHERE PREF_ID = 5) U1
  INNER JOIN USER U2
  ON U2.PREF_ID = U1.PREF_ID
GROUP BY U1.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

自己結合にするメリットは、このケースではなさそうに思えます。